# Cambiar Width OnClick by TagName

Tags: javascript, html, web

Muy buenas! Tengo una galeria muy simple. Un DIV y dentro IMGs con un width de 100px.
Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando pulses el button se cambie el width de todas las imagenes de ese div en concreto a px.
Si hay otro metodo mas eficiente se libre de ponerlo. Al final lo que me gustaria hacer son varios buttons con diferentes resoluciones que al pulsar cambie el width de todas las imagenes. 
Cuando pulso button no ocurre nada....
Gracias!!!

```
<button onclick="display240()">Thumbnail X 240PX</button>
        <div id="imageset_thumbsx240">
            <img src="images/001.jpg"width="100px">   <img src="images/003.jpg"width="100px">   <img src="images/004.jpg"width="100px">   <img src="images/005.jpg"width="100px">
            <img src="images/006.jpg"width="100px">   <img src="images/008.jpg"width="100px">   <img src="images/009.jpg"width="100px">   <img src="images/010.jpg"width="100px">
            <img src="images/011.jpg"width="100px">   <img src="images/013.jpg"width="100px">   <img src="images/014.jpg"width="100px">   <img src="images/015.jpg"width="100px">
            <img src="images/016.jpg"width="100px">   <img src="images/018.jpg"width="100px">   <img src="images/019.jpg"width="100px">   <img src="images/020.jpg"width="100px">
        </div>
```

JS

```
<script>
    function display240() {document.getElementsByTagName("img").style.width = "240px";}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función `getElementsByTagName` devuelve un array de objetos. Si lo recorres podrás cambiar el estilo a cada uno de ellos

```
function display240() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i<elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].style.width = "240px";
    }
}
```

**EDITO**
Si necesitas cambiar el estilo de las imágenes de un `div`, en vez de todo el documento, simplemente haces referencia al `div`, en vez de al `document`. En el ejemplo que expones, el `div` es "imageset_thumbsx240"

```
function display240() {
    var elems = imageset_thumbsx240.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i<elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].style.width = "240px";
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! esta es la solucion, todo perfecto. Una cosillas mas... Como selecciono el tag img de un div en concreto? para no cambiar todas las img del documento html

Comment: @Danilo, he editado la respuesta, es sencillo, cambias el `document` por el nombre del `div`

Comment: Gracias maquina! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas Danillo y bienvenido seas. Simplemente necesitas añadir la propiedad `name` a tus imagenes, para poder localizarlas correctamente.

```html
        <script>
    function display240() {document.getElementsByName("nombre").style.width = "240px";}
    </script>

<button onclick="display240()">Thumbnail X 240PX</button>
        <div id="imageset_thumbsx240">
            <img name="nombre" src="images/001.jpg" width="100px">   <img name="nombre" src="images/003.jpg" width="100px">   <img name="nombre" src="images/004.jpg" width="100px">   <img name="nombre" src="images/005.jpg" width="100px">
            <img name="nombre" src="images/006.jpg" width="100px">   <img name="nombre" src="images/008.jpg" width="100px">   <img name="nombre" src="images/009.jpg" width="100px">   <img name="nombre" src="images/010.jpg" width="100px">
            <img name="nombre" src="images/011.jpg" width="100px">   <img name="nombre" src="images/013.jpg" width="100px">   <img name="nombre" src="images/014.jpg" width="100px">   <img name="nombre" src="images/015.jpg" width="100px">
            <img name="nombre" src="images/016.jpg" width="100px">   <img name="nombre" src="images/018.jpg" width="100px">   <img name="nombre" src="images/019.jpg" width="100px">   <img name="nombre" src="images/020.jpg" width="100px">
        </div>
```

Comment: Lo siento pero no funciona. Lo he copiado y pegado tal cual esta y me pasa lo mismo, no cambia el width...

Comment: Prueba también con un getElementsByID y agrega en lugar de name, la propiedad 'id' a cada elemento

Comment: El problema de usar un getElementsByID, es que no puede usar el mismo id para cada imagen, y por lo tanto es mucho más tedioso cambiar las dimensiones de todas las imagenes al mismo tiempo. Con getElementsByClassName si puede funcionar también